# Displaying items from my php array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Ive had a lot of help reading some of the questions asked on this site so I figured I would post a question of my own. I've recently been messing around with arrays and was wondering how I would go about displaying certain items from an array I have.

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["kind"]=> string(25) "youtube#videoListResponse" ["etag"]=> string(57) ""blahblah"" ["pageInfo"]=> array(2) { ["totalResults"]=> int(1) ["resultsPerPage"]=> int(1) } ["items"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["kind"]=> string(13) "youtube#video" ["etag"]=> string(57) ""blahblah"" ["id"]=> string(11) "XS6ysDFTbLU" ["snippet"]=> array(9) { ["publishedAt"]=> string(24) "2014-08-15T17:22:04.000Z" ["channelId"]=> string(24) "UCnEiGCE13SUI7ZvojTAVBKw" ["title"]=> string(35) "Bill Gates ALS Ice Bucket Challenge" ["description"]=> string(212) "Bill Gates accepts Mark Zuckerbergâ€™s ALS Ice Bucket Challenge and nominates Elon Musk, Ryan Seacrest and Chris Anderson from TED to participate and raise awareness for ALS, also known as Lou Gehrigâ€™s Disease." ["thumbnails"]=> array(5) { ["default"]=> array(3) { ["url"]=> string(46) "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XS6ysDFTbLU/default.jpg" ["width"]=> int(120) ["height"]=> int(90) } ["medium"]=> array(3) { ["url"]=> string(48) "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XS6ysDFTbLU/mqdefault.jpg" ["width"]=> int(320) ["height"]=> int(180) } ["high"]=> array(3) { ["url"]=> string(48) "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XS6ysDFTbLU/hqdefault.jpg" ["width"]=> int(480) ["height"]=> int(360) } ["standard"]=> array(3) { ["url"]=> string(48) "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XS6ysDFTbLU/sddefault.jpg" ["width"]=> int(640) ["height"]=> int(480) } ["maxres"]=> array(3) { ["url"]=> string(52) "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XS6ysDFTbLU/maxresdefault.jpg" ["width"]=> int(1280) ["height"]=> int(720) } } ["channelTitle"]=> string(13) "thegatesnotes" ["categoryId"]=> string(2) "29" ["liveBroadcastContent"]=> string(4) "none" ["localized"]=> array(2) { ["title"]=> string(35) "Bill Gates ALS Ice Bucket Challenge" ["description"]=> string(212) "Bill Gates accepts Mark Zuckerbergâ€™s ALS Ice Bucket Challenge and nominates Elon Musk, Ryan Seacrest and Chris Anderson from TED to participate and raise awareness for ALS, also known as Lou Gehrigâ€™s Disease." } } ["statistics"]=> array(5) { ["viewCount"]=> string(8) "23231956" ["likeCount"]=> string(6) "206532" ["dislikeCount"]=> string(4) "4471" ["favoriteCount"]=> string(1) "0" ["commentCount"]=> string(5) "14548" } } } } }
```

so this is the array i'm trying to extract values from. Could someone maybe show me how to display the localized title, default thumbnail and viewcount with php. I think from there I can manage to get the rest figured out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

P.S.
I've tried to use the below code with no luck.

```
$MYarray = array($ARRAY_Data);
echo $MYarray['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount'];
```

$ARRAY_Data holds the array I posted at the top.

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: I've updated my question with a little more information sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the thing that's causing you problems is this:

```
$MYarray = array($ARRAY_Data);
```

That just adds another array around your original array, which doesn't seem like it should be necessary, and based on your var_dump output, if you hadn't done that, in the next line

```
echo $MYarray['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount'];
```

you're actually already using the correct array keys to get you the value you want. So just skip the `$MYarray = array($ARRAY_Data);` and use the same keys on the original array:

```
echo $ARRAY_Data['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount'];
```